# Dit-on «la probabilité que cela se produise» ou «la probabilité pour que cela se produise» ?

Tags: usage, prépositions, conjonctions, mathématiques

Je n’arrive pas à trouver de référence, je trouve les deux formulations mais la première me semble mieux.

Est-ce que les deux sont correctes ? Y a-t-il une différence ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On peut assez facilement comparer l'usage. En regardant les premières pages des listes d'occurrences, je ne vois quasiment pas d'usages parasites.

[image: probabilité que,probabilité pour que]

Donc au début de l'étude des probabilités, on écrivait « probabilité que », et je note au passage que le verbe de la subordonnée était en général à l'indicatif futur. Ensuite « probabilité pour que » s'est répandu au milieu du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, mais dans la deuxième moitié du siècle « probabilité que » est redevenu majoritaire. « Probabilité pour que » comme le « probabilité que » moderne sont suivis du subjonctif.

Comment: Ton graphique est très intéressant ! Comment l’as-tu obtenu ? Pourrais-tu donner un lien ?

Comment: @PhML Le graphique apparaît sur la page Google Ngrams vers laquelle pointe l'image. Pour obtenir l'image elle-même, remplace `/graph` par `/chart` dans l'URL. Pour plus de détails, voir http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-do-i-insert-an-actual-ngram-chart-into-my-post/1173#1173

Answer (score 2):

Les deux sont correctes. La première expression est légèrement moins lourde.

Comment: Des références ?

Comment: Le Larousse donne comme exemple la seconde forme [http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/probabilit%C3%A9/64032] et Wikipedia donne des citations de la première forme [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilit%C3%A9], donc c'est au choix.